# msbuild force optimization

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild

I'm building a C++ project from the command line using msbuild.

Is there a way to force the C++ optimization setting overriding the value for that configuration?

## Example:

Something like this (non-working example):

`msbuild mysolution.sln /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=release /p:Optimization=disabled`

The intention for that example is to use all the build settings from the release configuration except to override the optimization settings only.

Comment: Generally, there are properties behind property page settings but the names and values of optimization properties don't seem to be documented. You could generate a preprocessed version of the project file and examine it to track down how the optimization settings are passed to the [`CL` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/cl-task?view=vs-2022).